# How to use a CMake variable to choose which header file to include in a c program

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Is it possible to use a CMake variable to decide which header file will be included in a c program.
I have tried the following without success:

header_a.h ->is the file including the following code

```
#if (@CMAKE_VAR@ == "B")
    #include header.b
#else
    #include header.c
#endif
```

I have also tried the following with same failed results:
header_a.h

```
#ifdef CMAKE_VAR
#define CMAKE_VAR_SELECTION CMAKE_VAR
#endif

#if (CMAKE_VAR_SELECTION == "B")
   #include header.b
#else
   #include header.c
#endif
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you use `configure_file` on your header to expand the cmake variables?

Comment: Did you do anything on the CMake side? The C++ compiler and CMake won't magically communicate. I don't know where you got the `@CMAKE_VAR@` idea from.

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to define a corresponding macro for C/C++ code from CMake.

```
# your CMAKE variable
set(CMAKE_VAR "B")
# that would define macro constant CMAKE_VAR_B 
add_definitions(-DCMAKE_VAR_${CMAKE_VAR})
```

Then in the code you can use you proposed

```
#if defined(CMAKE_VAR_B)
    #include header.b
#else
    #include header.c
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMake's [`file(WRITE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/file.html#write) command to write the header so it contains the proper include declaration:

```
if (${CMAKE_VAR} EQUAL "B")
    file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_a.h"
"
#include <header.b>
"
    )
else()
    file(WRITE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/myheader.hpp"
"
#include <header.c>
"
    )
endif()
```